# Join sobre múltiples tablas en MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, join

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web sobre personajes Pokémon, la cual debe mostrar los siguientes datos: Nombre, Imagen, Categoria, Tipo, Habilidades (hasta 3) y Debilidades (hasta 3):

El modelo y las tablas sobre las que estoy trabajando es el siguiente:
[image: modelo relacional]

Las tablas "**PokemonTipo**", "**PokemonDebilidad**" y **PokemonHabilidad** guardan registros "muchos a muchos" de Tipos, Debilidades y Habilidades de cada Pokémon.

El **Select** que estoy usando es este.

```
SELECT po.idPokemon, po.nombre AS 'Pokemon', po.imagen, cat.nombre AS 'Categoria', ti.nombre 
AS 'Tipo', ha.nombre AS 'Habilidad', de.nombre AS 'Debilidad'
FROM Pokemon po 
INNER JOIN Categoria cat
ON po.idCategoria = cat.idCategoria
INNER JOIN PokemonTipo pt
ON po.idPokemon = pt.idPokemon
INNER JOIN Tipo ti
ON ti.idTipo = pt.idTipo
INNER JOIN PokemonHabilidad ph
ON po.idPokemon = ph.idPokemon
INNER JOIN Habilidad ha
ON ha.idHabilidad = ph.idHabilidad
INNER JOIN PokemonDebilidad pd
ON po.idPokemon = pd.idPokemon
INNER JOIN Debilidad de
ON de.idDebilidad = pd.idDebilidad
GROUP BY po.idPokemon
ORDER BY po.idPokemon
```

Los datos que obtengo son estos:
[image: Join de las tablas]

Como se observa en la imagen, con el Select que uso, solo obtengo una **Habilidad** y una **Debilidad** por cada Pokémon.

El problema que no he podido resolver es: **cómo obtener y separar en columnas distintas la Habilidad y Debilidad de cada Pokémon** con un mismo Select.

Por cada Pokémon debo tener los siguientes campos:

***Nombre, Imagen, Categoria, Tipo, Habilidad 1, Habilidad 2, Habilidad 3, Debilidad 1, Debilidad 2, Debilidad 3***

El Script de la base de datos, por si quieren hacer pruebas, se puede obtener en este enlace. https://github.com/jcesarux/pokebase/blob/master/pokebase.sql

Les agradecería un punto de vista distinto sobre cómo abordar el problema.

Saludos y gracias por el apoyo.!!

Comment: Sería muy útil si agregaras el script para crear las tablas con sus  datos para poder hacer pruebas.

Comment: Y si pruebas agregando a la cláusula `GroupBy` el _ha.nombre_? Actualmente estas agrupando sólo por el id del pokémon, debería ser el id y la habilidad no?

Comment: @Lobos coloque la referencia, para obtener el script de la base de datos.

Comment: Pienso que deberías romper con la relación muchos a muchos y después hacer lo que dice Paulo Urbano, es un buen punto.

Answer (score 0):

para poder obtener todas las habilidades en diferentes columnas hay que hacer subquery´s, no se si sea la manera más optima de realizarlo pero al menos funciona

```
SELECT po.idPokemon, po.nombre AS 'Pokemon', po.imagen, cat.nombre AS 'Categoria', ti.nombre AS 'Tipo', ha.nombre AS 'Habilidad1',
/*Se realizan dos subqurys para obtener la habildades */
(SELECT hab.nombre FROM Habilidad hab INNER JOIN PokemonHabilidad pha ON hab.idHabilidad = pha.idHabilidad WHERE po.idPokemon = pha.idPokemon AND nombre <> Habilidad1 LIMIT 1) AS habilidad2,
(SELECT hab.nombre FROM Habilidad hab INNER JOIN PokemonHabilidad pha ON hab.idHabilidad = pha.idHabilidad WHERE po.idPokemon = pha.idPokemon AND (nombre <> Habilidad2 AND nombre <> Habilidad1) LIMIT 1) AS habilidad3,
de.nombre AS 'Debilidad1',
/*Se realizan dos subqurys para obtener las debilidades */
(SELECT pe.nombre FROM Debilidad pe INNER JOIN PokemonDebilidad pde ON pe.idDebilidad = pde.idDebilidad WHERE po.idPokemon = pde.idPokemon AND pe.nombre <> Debilidad1 LIMIT 1) AS Debilidad2,
(SELECT pe.nombre FROM Debilidad pe INNER JOIN PokemonDebilidad pde ON pe.idDebilidad = pde.idDebilidad WHERE po.idPokemon = pde.idPokemon AND (pe.nombre <> Debilidad2 AND nombre <> Debilidad1) LIMIT 1) AS Debilidad3
FROM Pokemon po
INNER JOIN Categoria cat
ON po.idCategoria = cat.idCategoria
INNER JOIN PokemonTipo pt
ON po.idPokemon = pt.idPokemon
INNER JOIN Tipo ti
ON ti.idTipo = pt.idTipo
INNER JOIN PokemonHabilidad ph
ON po.idPokemon = ph.idPokemon
INNER JOIN Habilidad ha
ON ha.idHabilidad = ph.idHabilidad
INNER JOIN PokemonDebilidad pd
ON po.idPokemon = pd.idPokemon
INNER JOIN Debilidad de
ON de.idDebilidad = pd.idDebilidad
GROUP BY po.idPokemon
ORDER BY po.idPokemon
```

Esta un poco largo me lo acomode de esa manera para que seas capaz de entenderlo, si tienes alguna duda me la puedes hacer saber, saludos!!